# How do I automatically set meta commands when starting psql?

Tags: postgresql, psql

When I start a psql session, I would like certain meta commands to already be set.

For instance:

```
\x auto
\set ON_ERROR_STOP on
```

I was hoping to find an rc or config file but couldn't. The command line options don't seem comprehensive either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the `.psqlrc` file. [Per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html#AEN88713):

> `psqlrc` and `~/.psqlrc`
>
> Unless it is passed an `-X` or `-c` option, psql attempts to read and execute commands from the system-wide startup file (`psqlrc`) and then the user's personal startup file (`~/.psqlrc`), after connecting to the database but before accepting normal commands. These files can be used to set up the client and/or the server to taste, typically with `\set` and `SET` commands.